# What does double-tapping on the home button exactly do?

Tags: iphone, ios

What does double-tapping on the home button exactly do?

1. Does it list the applications running in background, OR
2. Does it list recently used applications?

I've implemented the  "Application does not run in background" in my Info.plist file. In spite of this my application shows on double tapping the home button !! Yes I have tried a clean build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shows all recently-used apps, not just the multi-tasking ones. If you try to tap your app now, it will start exactly like it was first launched, displaying the launch image first before initializing (calling `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and sending the relevant notifications).